# What software to use to build an interface for Python apps?

Tags: python

My colleagues and I have a lot of Python demos that we have made over time. If I wanted to create an interface to put all these demos (and other types of demos: video, url links, etc.), what would be an appropriate software to use?

I would like to have this interface to be interactive (able to easily add/remove apps at any time) and have it be able to display certain types of apps when we want it to.

Furthermore, I also want it to hold metadata on each of the apps (author, description, etc..)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

[wxPython](https://wxpython.org/) is an open source cross-platform GUI toolkit for the Python language. With wxPython software developers can create truly native user interfaces for their Python applications, that run with little or no modifications on Windows, Mac and Linux or other Unix-like systems.

More wx software

- [wxWidgets](https://wxwidgets.org/) – cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit
- [wxFormBuilder](https://github.com/wxFormBuilder/wxFormBuilder) – rapid application development tool for wxWidgets GUI design
- [wxGlade](http://wxglade.sourceforge.net/) – GUI designer for wxPython

Comment: thank you for your response and have looked into those options. However, I have opted to use bootstrap to build the front-end and pair it with elasticsearch to handle the back-end. (Just posted this fyi for anyone else who has a similar question)